# Pimcore: Retrieve Single Object List by Multiple Class Types

Tags: custom-lists, pimcore

I currently have a controller that pulls objects from the Pimcore Objects exactly how the sample data demonstrated.

What we need to accomplish with this build, is to allow for a "Featured" category to be assigned to any NewsArticle object or EventsArticle object. We need to pull a combined list from both `NewsArticle` and `EventsArticle` objects that also have the `Featured` category assigned to them. We need to keep track of all the IDs returned in this list, and exclude them from the single track lists so that they aren't displayed twice on the same page.

These are our two single track lists which work as expected, limited by custom properties that live on the document.

**Requirements:**

- Filter by `featured` category.
- Prevent any post from being listed twice.
- Able to sort by date `asc` or `desc`.

---

```
// TODO: List Featured News and Events Objects...
// $this->view->featured = $featuredList->getObjects();

// List News Objects...
$newsList = new Object\NewsArticle\Listing();
$newsList->setOrderKey( "date" );
$newsList->setOrder( "DESC" );
$newsList->setLimit( $this->document->getProperty( 'newsLimit' ) );
// TODO: Exclude any IDs in $this->view->featured
$this->view->news = $newsList->getObjects();

// List Events Objects...
$eventsList = new Object\EventsArticle\Listing();
$eventsList->setOrderKey( "date" );
$eventsList->setOrder( "DESC" );
$eventsList->setLimit( $this->document->getProperty( 'eventsLimit' ) );
// TODO: Exclude any IDs in $this->view->featured
$this->view->events = $eventsList->getObjects();
```

Answer (score 2):

This approach will give you the featured list:

```
$featuredListObj = \Pimcore\Model\Object::getByPath("featured-list");
$featuredListObjId = $featuredListObj->getId();

$eventClassId = \Pimcore\Model\Object\ClassDefinition::getByName("news")->getId();
$newsClassId = \Pimcore\Model\Object\ClassDefinition::getByName("event")->getId();

$combinedListing = new Pimcore\Model\Object\Listing();
$combinedListing->setCondition("o_className IN ('event','news') AND o_id IN (
    SELECT o_id FROM object_$eventClassId WHERE categories LIKE '%,$featuredListObjId,%'
    UNION SELECT o_id FROM object_$newsClassId WHERE categories LIKE '%,$featuredListObjId,%'
)");

foreach ($combinedListing as $item) {
    echo get_class($item) . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: The `WHERE featured = 1` would be a custom property instead of a category assignment, correct?

Comment: In my example it is a boolean field, but it can be any other type of field. Just check how it is saved in the database and query it like that.

Comment: The client would have to create this property on the object and fill it in. We were hoping to simplify the process by making "featured" an object functioning as a category, to provide drag-and-drop simplicity.

Comment: @GrafikMatthew I updated my answer to use instead a featured category.

Comment: Hmmm. I run into the same issue when adding the sort by date into the mix. I'm assuming its erroring on the elements which have no `date` property. How do I avoid this?

Comment: Please explain what is the actual issue and what do you want to achieve with date.

Comment: I'd like to be able to sort `asc` or `desc` by date.

Comment: The exact error I'm getting is `Mysqli prepare error: Unknown column 'date' in 'order clause'`

Comment: Sorry to say, I don't thank that's possible then with my approach. It uses the 'objects' table, which doesn't include any other fields from the object classes. Maybe you should have a common object for news and events, with specific fields within two different object bricks. That would be the correct way from data modelling point of view, but I understand that that makes the UI less friendly.

Answer (score 1):

After some toil I've figured out a way to do this. It may not be optimal, but it works and gets the job done.

The reason why I've found this way to be most effective is because `setCondition` will also check non-target classes for columns they might not have, causing the list to fail.

```
#
# Hybridized Featured Articles List
#

# Get News and Events Objects...
$hybridList = new Object\Listing();
$hybridList->setCondition( "o_className IN ( 'newsArticle', 'eventsArticle' )" );

# Get a list of IDs for News and Events that have the "featured" category...
$featuredList = array();
foreach( $hybridList->getObjects() as $obj ) {
    foreach( $obj->categories as $obj_cat ) {
        if( $obj_cat->o_key == 'featured' ) {
            $key = strtotime( $obj->date->date );
            $key .= str_pad( $obj->o_id, 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT );
            $featuredList[ $key ] = $obj;
            break;
        }
    }
}

# Sort and Slice the list...
if( $this->document->getProperty( 'featuredSort' ) == 'asc' ) {
    ksort( $featuredList ); // Oldest First
} else {
    krsort( $featuredList ); // Newest First
}
$this->view->featured = array_slice( $featuredList, 0, $this->document->getProperty( 'featuredLimit' ) );

#
# Audit the Hybridized Featured Articles List for IDs
#

$block_ids = array();
foreach( $this->view->featured as $featured ) {
    $block_ids[] = (int)$featured->o_id;
}

#
# News Articles List...
#

$newsList = new Object\NewsArticle\Listing();
$newsList->setOrderKey( "date" );
$newsList->setOrder( $this->document->getProperty( 'newsSort' ) == 'asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc' );
$newsList->setCondition( 'o_id NOT IN ('.implode( ',', $block_ids ).')' );
$newsList->setLimit( $this->document->getProperty( 'newsLimit' ) );
$this->view->news = $newsList->getObjects();

#
# Events Articles List...
#

$eventsList = new Object\EventsArticle\Listing();
$eventsList->setOrderKey( "date" );
$eventsList->setOrder( $this->document->getProperty( 'eventsSort' ) == 'asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc' );
$eventsList->setCondition( 'o_id NOT IN ('.implode( ',', $block_ids ).')' );
$eventsList->setLimit( $this->document->getProperty( 'eventsLimit' ) );
$this->view->events = $eventsList->getObjects();
```